# Whats the best approach in terms of database design for this situation

Tags: mysql, database

So i want to have three tables, the first will be a profiles table that will be linked to a users table, another will be a teams table that will contain all the teams and the third will be a tournaments table that will contain tournament data as well as the teams that are participating in that tournament. The way i would like it to work is that a profile can be linked to several teams and a team can be linked to several tournaments. What baffles me for example is how i would store teams for a tournament i cant create a column for each since i the number of teams is not constant.

Thank  you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

You will want an association table to connect users and teams, and teams and tournaments.

For example, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_teams(
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    team_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX(user_id, team_id)
);
```

You can then connect an individual user to as many teams as you want. You would create a similar table to map between teams and tournaments.